# How to click a modal button inside a clickable modal div with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a clickable div that opens a modal with Bootstrap, but inside I have a button that opens a modal too.
The result is that when I click on the button it opens the div modal too.
How can fix it? How can I set the button to be on top of the div?

```
<div class="mydiv" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#divclick">
    <h2>My Clickable div</h2>

    <button id="other_details" type="button" style="margin-top:9px;float:center;" class="btn btn-info btn-sd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MoreDetails">More details</button>

<!-- Modal More Details-->
<div id="MoreDetails" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<!-- Modal Code-->
...
</div>


</div>

<div id="divclick" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<!-- Modal Code-->
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), multiple open modals are not supported but it requires custom code to make it function.